# What kind of proxy server is this?

Tags: sockets, tcp, proxy

I want to use this as a proxy server to connect many different clients with servers. Here is what I'm looking to do:

The server software on a user's computer would connect to a proxy server that is running on a VPS. It would pass in some kind of Key or authentication info to identify itself and then would maintain a persistent TCP connection to the proxy server.

A client application running on a mobile device or other computer would connect to the proxy server and pass in some kind of Key or authentication info. The proxy server would match the connection between the client and server based on their authentication info, and then forward all data back and fourth between the connections.

The proxy server would need to be able to handle multiple clients and servers connecting to it at once and use the authentication info to pair them up. There could be multiple clients connecting to the same server at the same time too. The connection from the client and server would both be outbound so that they are not blocked by firewalls. I wrote the client and server software, so I can make them work with any specific proxy.

What is the name of this kind of proxy server? And can anyone recommend any?

Thanks!

Comment: More of a secure connection broker really.

Comment: Where would I find software or a service provider to use for this?